# JavaScript - How to know if an element is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game. My problem is that my code allows to rewrite X or O even if one of the squares already contain X or O. I'm using an if statement to write either X or O depending on a number variable that increases by one every time. I would like to add another conditional that only allows X or O to be written if my  tag is empty. How do i do this?. Note: Only javascript please, since I haven't started learning jQuery yet. 
Thanks a bunch in advance!

JS

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var player = 1;
var str = "";

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
     if( player % 2 === 0 && tds[i] !== "<td>X</td>"  && tds[i] !==
     "<td>O</td>"){
       this.textContent = "O";
     } else if (player % 2 !== 0 && tds[i] === "" ) {
       this.textContent = "X";
     }
   player++;

  });
}
```

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note your code has a number of syntax and semantic errors - please try to post working code. Also note that if you can do `this.textContent = "X";` (not sure what that `this` should be though...) you can also do `this.textContent.length === 0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just check the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property of an element, which returns a `Nodelist`.

If it's length is 0, then your element is empty.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#container")
console.log(elem.childNodes.length)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Careful as line breaks count as `text` though.

Comment: This will get around the blank / line breaks as text problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722545/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-div-is-empty-without-jquery-but-with-javascript

Comment: `childNondes` also returns comment nodes. So if it has no elements and text, but has a comment tag inside, the length will be > 0. It is better to loop through the childNodes and return a list of `Node.TEXT_NODE` and `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`. Then check the length on the array. In the letter case, it also needs trimming, because the browser creates empty text nodes around comments.

Comment: @GevorgHakobyan Can you edit this into the answer?
 It's a very good and important note.

Comment: @nicholaswmin, I just wanted to remind about the limitations. We could also do `elem.outerHTML.length`, but again, it also takes comment tags into account. If we expect emptiness as no text nodes, than `elem.innerText.length` (taking into account empty text nodes) and `elem.innerText.trim().length` (for completely textless element nodes).

Answer (score 5):

`node.childNodes.length` will pick up spaces or other elements inside the node you're checking, to include any spacing or returns from formatting.

e.g. The following returns `3`

```
<td>
  <!-- returns NodeList(3) [text, comment, text] -->
</td>
```

`<span>&nbsp;<span>` will result in `1` and `<span>&nbsp;<span>&nbsp;</span></span>` will result in `2` with the above method.

Unless you're sure of your data or cleansing your data source well, I'd use the following to test against node emptiness.

```
// <div id="SomeElement" />

function isEmpty(node) {
  return node.textContent.trim() === "";
}

isEmpty(SomeElement);

// or

Element.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return this.textContent.trim() === "";
}

SomeElement.isEmpty();
```

```js
function emptyElementNode(node) {
  return node.textContent.trim() === "";
}

var xo = TicTacToe.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < xo.length; ++i) {

 if (emptyElementNode(xo[i])) {
    xo[i].classList.add('highlight');
    xo[i].textContent = "⚬";
  }

}
```

```css
#TicTacToe {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.063rem;
  width: 6.25rem;
  height: 6.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: -0.063rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#TicTacToe {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.063rem;
  width: 6.25rem;
  height: 6.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: -0.063rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#TicTacToe div{
  position: relative;
}

#TicTacToe div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(6.25rem / 3);
  height: calc(6.25rem / 3);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  outline: 1px solid #222;
}

#TicTacToe .highlight::before {
  background: #ddd;
}

#TicTacToe div{
  position: relative;
}

#TicTacToe div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(6.25rem / 3);
  height: calc(6.25rem / 3);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  outline: 1px solid #222;
}

#TicTacToe .highlight::before {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="TicTacToe">
  <div>⚬</div>
  <div>×</div>
  <div>×</div>
  <div>⚬</div>
  <div>⚬</div>
  <div>×</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>×</div>
  <div>⚬</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `innerHtml` property to check if element contain anything. But I would prefer to add class `marked` when you set the html `X or O`. Then in your js check if the element has class `marked`.
Add class on click event of `td` using:

```
function mark(e)
{
var isMarked = hasClass(e,"marked");
if(!isMarked )
{
e.className+= " marked";
//add X or O
}
else
{
//do something else
}
function hasClass(element, className) {
    return element.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(element.className);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="mark(this)"></td>
       .
       .
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

HasClass Reference: http://sonnyt.com/blog/development/javascript-check-if-element-has-class

Answer (score 2):

This method has full browser support: `yourNode.hasChildNodes()`

> The Node.hasChildNodes() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether the given Node has child nodes or not.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `innerHTML` property of your elements to ascertain if they contain anything- in your case `X` or `O`.

So, the condition should look like this.

```
if( player % 2 === 0 && tds[i].innerHTML !== "X"  && tds[i].innerHTML !== "O") {

}
```

Comment: There may be other bugs in your code. But this is one way you can check the contents of a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

please find working solution below.

```js
var player = 1;
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('td');
var title = document.getElementById('title');

function switchPlayer(currentPlayer) {
  if (currentPlayer === 1) {
    player = 2;
    title.innerHTML = 'Player: 2(O)'
  } else {
    player = 1;
    title.innerHTML = 'Player: 1(X)'
  }
}

blocks.forEach(function(block) {
  block.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!block.innerHTML) {
      if (player === 1) {
        block.innerHTML = 'X';
      } else {
        block.innerHTML = 'O';
      }
      switchPlayer(player)
    }
  })
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">
Player: 1 (X)
</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```