# How do i check if an element (div) is empty without jquery but with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i really just want to check if an element is empty or not with javascript but without jquery. When the element is empty, the code should return true, and the opposite when it has content in it.

Say for example i have this div that needs to be checked if it's empty:

```
<div id="foo">

</div>
```

And since it is empty, the code should return true. But in the case below:

```
<div id="cats">
<h1>Cats are awesome!</h1>
</div>
```

It should return false.

EDIT: What i really need is to check if it contains any children. I found out the answer, you can find it in the comments section.

Comment: `innerHTML.trim().length == 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it seems there is an easier solution to this problem, which i realised when i saw that someone marked this post as a duplicate.

You can just use

```
if(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML.trim().length == 0) {
   <code to execute here>
}
```

Thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

You might use `document.getElementById().innerHTML` or `document.querySelector().innerHTML`. Then just check if the returned string contains anything.

```js
function hasAnything(selector) {
 return document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML.trim().length > 0;
}

const pre = document.querySelector('#pre')

pre.innerHTML = hasAnything('#test1');
pre.innerHTML += '\n' + hasAnything('#test2');
pre.innerHTML += '\n' + hasAnything('#test3');
```

```html
<div id='test1'>Content</div>
<div id='test2'><p>something else</p></div>
<div id='test3'></div>

<pre id='pre'></pre>
```

Aaand here is it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/3k9u9tev/

Comment: I was just typing up the same answer.

Comment: And that is where i'm stuck.. How do i check if something is empty like that?
using null or undefined in an if statement doesn't work..?

Comment: Updated the answer with example. take a look

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely return a string depending on the use of whitespace in your code, so you can trim the contents and then check if the string is empty.

```
var contents = document.querySelector("#cats");
var result = contents.innerHTML.trim();
result == "" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
```

Comment: Don't teach people to `result == "" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);` - Simply do: `console.log( result === "" )`

Comment: Compelling argument.

Comment: PS: The question originally asked how they could return true if an element was empty. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯